# Convert NSColor String representation<->hex in php

Tags: php, objective-c, cocoa, nscolor

I am looking for a way to precisely(!) convert a `NSColor` string representation to a hex color in php (and vice versa).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is the string representation coming from? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa2007/qa1576.html ?

You can port it to PHP anytime.

Regards

Sorin